# Erlang multiple mnesia databases in the same application or in a application tree dependency

Tags: database, erlang, mnesia

To use mnesia, the path on the filesystem to the relative mnesia scheme to be used must be set as the environment variable of the application(application:set_env('path_to_schema')).
Now 2 questions arise:

1. Is there a way to specify 2 different mnesia databases to use within the application?
2. Let's assume we have 2 different applications that use mnesia.
   So we have application A using the mnesia scheme in path X and application B using the mnesia scheme in path Y.
   Now let's assume that application B is used as a dependency on application A and thus A will encompass application B.
   At that point what happens in terms of using the mnesia database? Will folder X or folder Y be used? Or will they be used independently within the relative application scope?

I thank anyone who answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to run two different copies of mnesia on the same erlang node at the same time.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply.So, regarding question 2, only one of the 2 specified paths will be used at the expense of the other right?

Comment: Yes. Whenever the mnesia application is started, it will load up the configured schema directory at that time and will not use any other dir while it's running.

Note that both applications can still create and use their own tables in the same schema dir, as long as there is no conflict.

Comment: Ah ok ok so an environment variable common to all applications is always used. Thank you very much for your responses and attention.